Equation Misalignment with Springer Nature LaTeX Template Using [iicol] Option
When using Springer Nature’s LaTeX template and selecting the "[iicol]" formatting option, as requested by the Journal of Cluster Computing, the equation extends beyond the first column and appears partially in the second column, as shown in the attached screenshot.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,iicol]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

%% as per the requirement new theorem styles can be included as shown below
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}


\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

%%=============================================================%%
%% GivenName    -> \fnm{Joergen W.}
%% Particle -> \spfx{van der} -> surname prefix
%% FamilyName   -> \sur{Ploeg}
%% Suffix   -> \sfx{IV}
%% \author*[1,2]{\fnm{Joergen W.} \spfx{van der} \sur{Ploeg} 
%%  \sfx{IV}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}
%%=============================================================%%

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

%%==================================%%
%% Sample for unstructured abstract %%
%%==================================%%

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

%%================================%%
%% Sample for structured abstract %%
%%================================%%

% \abstract{\textbf{Purpose:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.
% 
% \textbf{Methods:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.
% 
% \textbf{Results:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.
% 
% \textbf{Conclusion:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.}

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

%%\pacs[JEL Classification]{D8, H51}

%%\pacs[MSC Classification]{35A01, 65L10, 65L12, 65L20, 65L70}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

\[
P(B_{6048\times10^8\:,\:p}=1) = \binom{6,048\times10^8}{1} \times p\times(1-p)^{10^6-1} = 1
\]
\[
p\times(1-p)^{10^6-1} = 1 / (6,048\times10^8) 
\]

Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset article if it is accepted. 

\section{Results}\label{sec2}

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. 

\section{Equations}\label{sec4}

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.

\end{document}



Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You might either want to use the icomma package or use siunitx to properly format your numbers.

\[ is always a single line equation, and your equation does not fit in a column use \begin{align*} from amsmath to split it over two lines at a suitable point, you should anyway be using such an environment as you should never have \[\] followed by another \[..\]  as you get  ugly white space between them as you show, set the pair in a single display environment

It's not misaligned: the equation is too long to fit.
Use multlined from mathtools. I also added siunitx which not only eases numeric input, but ensures uniformity across the document.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,iicol]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}


\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

%%=============================================================%%
%% GivenName    -> \fnm{Joergen W.}
%% Particle -> \spfx{van der} -> surname prefix
%% FamilyName   -> \sur{Ploeg}
%% Suffix   -> \sfx{IV}
%% \author*[1,2]{\fnm{Joergen W.} \spfx{van der} \sur{Ploeg} 
%%  \sfx{IV}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}
%%=============================================================%%

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

%%==================================%%
%% Sample for unstructured abstract %%
%%==================================%%

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

%%================================%%
%% Sample for structured abstract %%
%%================================%%

% \abstract{\textbf{Purpose:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.
% 
% \textbf{Methods:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.
% 
% \textbf{Results:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.
% 
% \textbf{Conclusion:} The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. The abstract must not include subheadings (unless expressly permitted in the journal's Instructions to Authors), equations or citations. As a guide the abstract should not exceed 200 words. Most journals do not set a hard limit however authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to.}

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

%%\pacs[JEL Classification]{D8, H51}

%%\pacs[MSC Classification]{35A01, 65L10, 65L12, 65L20, 65L70}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the 
background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). 
The introduction should not include subheadings.
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}
P(B_{\num{6,048E8},p}=1) \\
= \binom{\num{6,048E8}}{1} \times p\times(1-p)^{10^6-1} = 1
\end{multlined}
\\
p\times(1-p)^{10^6-1} = 1 / (\num{6,048E8})
\end{gather*}

Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however 
authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the 
journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level 
preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some 
stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), 
including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset 
article if it is accepted. 

\section{Results}\label{sec2}

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. 
Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. 
Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. 

\section{Equations}\label{sec4}

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. 
Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. 
Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.

\end{document}


By the way: textcomp is no longer necessary; only one among algorithmicx or algpseudocode should be loaded, take your pick.
